# global variable for getenv()?

Tags: c, glibc

Which is the global variable which holds all the environmental variables for getenv() ? In what glibc file is this var filled with env vars ?

I believe it to be **environ but when I set an env var in bash it only ouputs the SSH_AGENT_PID env var. Why is SSH_AGENT_PID set and why is it the only one that is set ?

```
DOCUMENT_ROOT='/foopath/'; export DOCUMENT_ROOT
```

```
int main(void)
{
extern char **environ;
printf("%s\n", *environ); // outputs: SSH_AGENT_PID=2822
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`char **environ` is `NULL`-terminated array of strings, so you should try:

```
extern char **environ;
char **p;
for (p = environ; *p; p++) {
    printf ("%s\n", *p);
}
```

In other words, `environ[0]` is pointer to first env variable, `environ[1]` to second etc. Last element in `environ` array is `NULL`.

Comment: And there's no guarantee that the list of variables is any particular order, and in some (unusual) circumstances, there might be two entries for a single variable.  It used to be the case that the environment was also passed into POSIX-ish programs if you used `int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)` for the main function declaration.  However, neither the 2003 nor the 2008 standard mentions this possibility, so I guess it is not guaranteed.  MacOS X still supports it, and so probably do most variations of Unix (it was documented for 7th Edition Unix in 1979).

Comment: Conventionally implemented by ``#include <unistd.h>`` rather than ``extern char **environ``. The variable is exported by glibc and declared in ``glibc//posix/environ.c``.

Comment: Does the C standard guarantee that this works? 8-\