# How do I use **environ from unistd.h to search for the right path?

Tags: c++, linux, path

Hi I'm trying to use `execvp()` in conjunction with the `**environ` variable to find the right path for a command the user puts in.

The problem is I don't really understand how to do this. I know I could just attempt to open the command files to check if they exist but I don't understand how to get the paths I need to search from `**environ`.

Comment: Where does `**environ` come from? The only ways I know how to do this is to either use `getenv("PATH")` which returns just a string, which is a list of path variables typically colon-separated. You could use `strtok` to parse this.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127614/global-variable-for-getenv  You'll need to flip through the array of strings and search for the PATH variable.  Once you find the PATH string you can parse the paths contained in the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char *start, *end;
    char ch;
    char* path = getenv("PATH");

    if (!path) {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not get $PATH, exiting\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    start = path;
    do {
        end = strchr(start, ':');
        if (!end) {
            printf("%s\n", start);
        } else {
            ch = *end;
            *end = '\0';
            printf("%s\n", start);
            *end = ch;
        }
        start = end + 1;
    } while (end != NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

This small program demonstrates how you can get separate paths from env[PATH].

Answer (score 0):

man execvp:

> execvp() will duplicate the actions  of  the
>          shell  in  searching  for  an executable file

Thus, you don't have to use *the **environ variable to find the right path for a command*; `execvp()` does it for you.